# How to get all possibilities of adding two indexes inside an infinite array in c++

Tags: c++, arrays

Ok so I am learning c++ and I got stumped with this in the language. Ok so say I have an infinite list ,and I want to figure out all the possible additions with it. EX [1,2,3]   = 1 +2, 1+3, 2+1, 2+3, 3+1, 3+2.... and it would be with a list that would be so huge that I wouldn't be able to put every specific index into there. 
Here were I ideas I was thinking ,but didn't work

```
bool sum(){
int b[] = {1, 5, 3, 9};
int n;
int equation;
    for(n = 0; n < 4; ++n){
        equation = Array[n] + Array [n+1 || n +2 || n+3 || n+4];
    if(equation == 10){
        return true;
}

   }
    return false;
    }
```

I swear if feels like I am missing an equation or it's something right under my nose.

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. An infinite list, impossible? So huge you cant put every specific index in there? What does that mean?

Comment: So what I meant by infinite list is that it wouldn't matter how many indexes I put in there. So the thing would still add everything and get all the possible sums with two indexs in the array. if I did 6 indexes or 100000000 index. It wouldn't matter the amount ,but I can't manually put every index in there to get all the possible combinations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this situation, you want to use a nested for loop.

The logic goes as follows: for every element in b, also check every element in b, and see if the sum adds up to 10.

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < sizeof(b); ++i){ //.length returns syntax error with //arrays
    for (size_t j = 0; j < sizeof(b); ++j){// same as previously stated
        if (i == j) continue;    //So that you don't add the number to itself

        if (b[i] + b[j] == 10){
            return true;
        }
    }
}
return false
```

Output:

```
1
```

we know one is true so we know this solves the problem

Comment: Based on this `Ok so say I have an infinite list ,and I want to figure out all the possible additions with it` and the question title, it is unlikely that this is an answer to the unknown question.

Comment: I understand what you're saying, but if you look at his example and what he wants, it really seems like this is what he's trying to accomplish. I thought that by 'infinite list' the poster maybe means an array of unspecified length.

Comment: hey this is the OP here. I will try out the double for loop to see if it works and will give and update by marking this as an answer if it works. Now time to clear up confusion with the question. So I am wanting to see if the thing could work no matter the size of the list. The algorithm wouldn't make a difference if I had 100 or 1000000000 indexes and add each and every index with each other.[1,2] 1+2, 2+1.  Just to clear up confusion.

Comment: thank you for the answer. I fixed the syntax error and edited it. It works perfect. Thank you so much!!!!!!!

Comment: @Phil Your answer needs fixing. You are considering `(i , j)` as well as `(j , i)`. Your inner loop ought to be `for (size_t j = 0; j < i; ++j)`

Comment: @NiNisanNijackle Woops haha, good catch. Been spending some time  coding in non-C++ languages

Comment: @Phil it’s ok. I accidentally use python instead of Swift also. Thanks for your answer though